# My script downloads the source of the page and not the actual file

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a problem with a downloading script.. So I made an uploading script -> it adds the files in a folder called Uploads and inserts id, filename and link into the database.But I can't find a way to download the uploaded file. Here's my download script:

```
 <?php
     include('config.php');
     $dwquery = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT id, filename FROM files");

     $id = intval($_GET['id']); 
         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($dwquery)) {
            echo '<a href="download.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['filename'].'</a><br />';
        }

       $download = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT link FROM files WHERE id=$id");
        $link = mysqli_fetch_array($download);

        if($id != '') {
        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$link[0]);
        readfile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/project/' .$link[0]);
        }

    ?>
```

When I select which file to download it just downloads the source code of the page and not the actual file.

Edit: It actually downloads the source code of download.php + the text / code that is inside the file I want to download. So it gets the echo:

```
echo '<a href="index.php"> Index </a> / <a href="upload.php"> Upload </a> / <a href="download.php"> Download </a> / <a href="logout.php"> Logout </a><br />';
```

And the downloaded file is:

```
<a href="index.php"> Index </a> / <a href="upload.php"> Upload </a> /
<a href="download.php"> Download </a> / <a href="logout.php"> Logout
</a><br /><a href="download.php?id=6">test1.php</a><br /><a
href="download.php?id=5">test2.txt</a><br />

and here's the actual code of the file
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code reads like this:

```
Show list of files
IF a download id is provided:
    Show the content of that file
```

It should read like this:

```
IF a download id is provided
    Show the content of that file
ELSE
    Show list of files
```

---

It is possible you are also getting the path of the file wrong as you have no error checking on the existence of the file.

Comment: Well the path is not wrong for sure. I've tried uploading a .txt file with some text inside it and then I downloaded it. The downloaded file contained something like: the menu of the site and then the text which was inside the text file.